# Help with SED syntax : unterminated `s' command

Tags: regex, sed, cygwin

**Edit: I'm using CYGWIN/GNU sed version 4.1.5 on windows Vista and I want a case insensitive search**

I want to use sed to replace inline, the following:

> c:\DEV\Suite\anything here --- blah 12 334 xxx zzzzz etc\Modules etc

**Edit:** anything here --- blah 12 334 xxx zzzzz etc means anything could appear here. Sorry for omitting that.

In a file with lines like

```
FileName="c:\DEV\Suite\anything here --- blah 12 334 xxx zzzzz etc\Modules\.... snipped ...."
```

with a value I supply, say :

> Project X - Version 99.98

So the file ends up with:

```
FileName="c:\DEV\Suite\Project X - Version 99.98\Modules\.... snipped ...."
```

My attempt:

```
c:\temp>sed -r -b s/Dev\\Suite\\.*\\Modules/dev\\suite\\simple\\/g test.txt
```

However I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command
```

Thanks.
Edit:
I've already tried added quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the '\\' before the '/'.  Apparently you need 4 backslashes.

```
sed -r -b "s/Dev\\\\Suite\\\\.*\\\\Modules/dev\\\\suite\\\\simple\\\\/g" test.txt
```

I think the shell is interpreting the '\\' into a '\' before passing it to sed, and then sed is doing the same thing on what it gets.

Single quotes would work, so:

```
sed -r -b 's/Dev\\Suite\\.*\\Modules/dev\\suite\\simple\\/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Actually sorry: The double quotes does work but the single one doesn't.

Comment: I tested quotes and backslashes on a WinXP cygwin bash shell.  What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If I use "\\\" where you have "\\", it works for me.  With the double backslashes, the way it gets parsed evidently has a backslash escaping the terminating "/" of the substitution expression.  (I still get the error if I replace ".*" with ".+".)

(Amusingly, I had to add more backslashes to get this to post properly -- SO ate a few of them!)

Comment: just to be clear:I change all the double back slashes to triples?

Comment: Yes, that's what worked for me.  I forgot to mention that I also used double-quotes around the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Got it: Replace the **.*** with **.+**

```
sed -r -b s/Dev\\Suite\\.+\\Modules/dev\\suite\\simple\\/g test.txt
```

Comment: If that works, then the likely problem was your shell expanding .* .  The quotes should have prevented the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of sed your using.  I'm not familiar with the -b option.

First, I'd suggest using the *i* regex flag, to make it case insensitive.  Your example of DEV won't match your regex of Dev.

I suspect the problem your running into is how your version of sed interprets backslash characters.

I'd suggest using the sed bundled with Cygwin.  With single quotes, it seems to work for me.

```
echo 'c:\DEV\Suite\anything here --- blah 12 334 xxx zzzzz etc\Modules\' | sed -r 's/Dev\\Suite\\.*\\Modules/dev\\suite\\simple\\/gi'
c:\dev\suite\simple\\
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with -b either.  Appears to be a cygwin thing to prevent conversion of lineendings.

Answer (score 0):

well...

```
sed -e s/"anything here --- blah 12 334 xxx zzzzz etc"/"Project X - Version 99.98"/g test.txt
```

worked fine

(The compliant about the unterminated 's' was because of the unescaped '/')

Answer (score 0):

Funny I was having the same issue in one directory but the same command worked in other directories on the same machine. This is the command I was working with

export version=`grep "version.*SNAPSHOT.*version" pom.xml |sed -e 's|<version>||g'|sed -e 's|</version>||g'|sed -e "s|\t* *||g"`; cat sonar-project.properties.template |sed -e "s/BUILDVERSION/$version/g">sonar-project.properties

when I changed the * to + it worked.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Will rename:

TV Show - 376 [720p].mkv
TV Show - 377 [720p].mkv

to

376.mkv
377.mkv

works under cygwin.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *; do
  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -r -b 's/^.*[ ]([0-9]*)[ ].*$/\1.mkv/'`";
done
```