# How to change IP Address in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I am developing a system in PHP wherein I can change the IP Address and subnet mask in a web form.

Here is what I try currently:

```
<pre><code><?php

echo "Old IP: ".$old_ip;
echo "New IP: ".$stat_ip;

system("sed -i 's|".$old_ip."|".$stat_ip."|g' /etc/.../.../ifcfg-eth0");

?>
```

I get the error `unterminated 's' command`

What is the right syntax for `sed` in this case?

Comment: Do you escape your variables so they don't contain regex special characters?

Comment: If all you do is to call `system()`, why require an installation of PHP plus an additional, thin, really thin indirection?

Comment: If I get an invalid command, it'd start by printing the command in order to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

How about you do it like this instead, it might be easier to spot the "error" when you can see the command you are trying to execute:

```
$command = "sed -i 's|".$old_ip."|".$stat_ip."|g' /etc/.../.../ifcfg-eth0";

echo "Executing command: $command";

system($command);
```

This way, it will be easier for you to debug the command.

The error message indicates that your command is somewhat malformed. [Here's a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269788/help-with-sed-syntax-unterminated-s-command).

Comment: thanks for this...I tried but still the problem is "unterminated 's' command"

Comment: @hmbarit, yes, but it might be easier for you to debug it. Check the link to the similar problem I stated in my answer. They got the same error as you did when using `sed`.

Comment: thanks! i checked the link, its value is fix, my case is the value is dynamic..if I make the value as fix (not variable)...it changes the file, but when it is a variable, there's an error message.

Comment: @hmbarit, My suggestion is, use my code above, check the output and make it work with a static case first then move over and just "replace" the sections that are dynamic. That's the easiest approach.

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to mark answers as "Accepted answer" to the left of the answers if they helped you. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score -1):

> Usage: sed [OPTION]...
>   {script-only-if-no-other-script}
>   [input-file]...
>
> -n, --quiet, --silent
>                    suppress automatic printing of pattern space   -e script,
>   --expression=script
>                    add the script to the commands to be executed   -f
>   script-file, --file=script-file
>                    add the contents of script-file to the commands to be
>   executed   --follow-symlinks
>                    follow symlinks when processing in place   -i[SUFFIX],
>   --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>                    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
>   -l N, --line-length=N
>                    specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
>   --posix
>                    disable all GNU extensions.   -r, --regexp-extended
>                    use extended regular expressions in the script.   -s,
>   --separate
>                    consider files as separate rather than as a single
>   continuous
>                    long stream.   -u, --unbuffered
>                    load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush
>                    the output buffers more often
>         --help     display this help and exit
>         --version  output version information and exit
>
> If no -e, --expression, -f, or --file
>   option is given, then the first
>   non-option argument is taken as the
>   sed script to interpret.  All
>   remaining arguments are names of input
>   files; if no input files are
>   specified, then the standard input is
>   read.
>
> E-mail bug reports to: bonzini@gnu.org
>   . Be sure to include the word `sed''
>   somewhere in the`Subject:'' field.

Comment: thanks for this...but I am just a newbie in linux command. how can I apply this to my project?